# Not able to link to Qt 5.9.2, CMake always links to system installed 5.5.1

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to upgrade my project to Qt 5.9.2 since I believe Qt 5.9 has better C++17 compatibility than 5.5 (default in Ubuntu 16.04)

I installed 5.9.2 using the online installer in my home directory and set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/home/karnik/Tools/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/libs/cmake` but `find_package(Qt5 5.9.2 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)` reported the error,

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:75 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.9".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1
```

I also tried setting it to just `/home/karnik/Tools/Qt/5.9.2`

I then set `Qt5_DIR` inside my CMakeLists.txt to `/home/karnik/Tools/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/` and the error got solved but `MESSAGE("Qt Version is " ${Qt5Widgets_VERSION})` showed that it was still using 5.5.1.

I then set `Qt5Widgets_DIR` to `/home/karnik/Tools/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/` and the version showed 5.9.2.

But weirdly, `MESSAGE(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})` showed that it was still pointing to the old files inside /usr/include

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++-64/usr/include

How can I get it to point to the right libraries?

TIA!

Comment: Have you clear the cache (file `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory) before attempting to get another QT version?

Comment: Yep, I delete my build folder each time

Comment: IIRC the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should be set to the root dir of your Qt installation (i.e., /home/karnik/Tools/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64 ), and you need to delete the whole cache before applying this change.  As an alternative to adding Qt5 through the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, you can follow the approach referred to as [finding Qt5 the right way](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-finding-qt5-the-right-way/).